# What is this icon with a messaging icon enclosed by a SIM card's icon in status bar?

Tags: notification-icons, samsung-galaxy-s-9

Can anyone tell me what the chat icon on the status bar is and how I can access it. This showed itself after a recent security update. I'm not sure if it's a message that I have not opened yet. I have checked all my messages and found none. Also, received messages are usually on the left side of the status bar.

[image]

Comment: The symbol looks like a SIM card and the icon inside like a message. Just guessing here, but there's a chance this refers to a network message (such as those used to configure your mobile carrier and so on ... in some networks you can also subscribe to additional messages, so this could be one of those).

Answer (score 9):

It's a SIM icon.

To change it, go to Settings → Connections →SIM card manager → choose SIM1/SIM2 icon.

[image: IMG:]

(Tap to enlarge)